# How can I effectively override DEFAULT_CURRENCY_VALUES - a constant in ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I created an initializer that overrides one of the values in this hash, but it didn't affect the output when I called the method (number_to_currency) in my views.

Comment: Did you restart your server after adding the initializer? Please show the code for the initializer so we can look for errors.

Answer (score 2):

overriding the DEFAULT_CURRENCY_VALUES doesn't work.

you should add this to your locale file:

```
# for Brazilian Portuguese
pt-BR:
  number:
    format:
      unit: "R$"
      separator: ","
      delimiter: "."
      precision: 2
      significant: false
      strip_insignificant_zeros: false
```

Comment: that's cool, but all I wanted to do was hide the .00 since all the prices are in whole dollar values.

Thanks for confirming that overriding this constant doesn't work - but what's the point of it in that case?